# Remove elements from multidimensional array where [2] = x

Tags: php, arrays

I saw many similar questions, but they seemed to be slightly different in that if *any* value was x, remove that element. If I've missed the Q&A, apologies.

I have an array of the form:

```
0 => ("A Name", 22, 33, 44, 55)
1 => ("Another", 2, 3, 4, 5)
etc
```

I want to essentially perform "If $array[*][2] = 33, remove that element", which in this case would remove A Name's record.

I'm relatively confident unset() & a foreach loop are required, but I'm honestly not sure how. I'm not sure how to use the foreach for a specific inner array value, but all outer array values.

**EDIT:** Current progress is essentially blundering around cluelessly with this:

```
        foreach($tempArray{$i} as $key => $value) {
            if ($value[2] == 33) { unset($array[$key]); }
        }
```

Comment: Can you share what you have tried with us?

Comment: first things first, that's not a multidimensional array unless you're just typing it out like that to represent a multidimensional array

Comment: @KaiQing Just pseudo to give an idea of structure.

Comment: will the array remain the same regardless of the values? meaning... will you always want to delete the 2nd position in first array? or How do you see this working?

Comment: If the 2nd (e.g.) value = x on any element, delete that element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you sort of tried, so try this:

```
foreach($array as $key => $val) {
    if($val[2] == 33) {
        unset($array[$key]);
    }
}
```

Not sure what the `$tempArray{$i}` was.  `foreach` will iterate through the array where you can use the key and value.

Comment: $tempArray{$i} was due to having 6-7 different temp arrays that are required. It's.. a long story. Also, this seems to work to a degree, having issues with the index though I believe. Thanks.

Comment: Actually I think it should be `foreach($array[] as $key => $val) {`

Comment: @AleOtero93: Uh no not in PHP.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a different approach, taking use of php functions such [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) and [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) (this one PHP 5.5 +);

```
$array = [
  ["A Name", 22, 33, 44, 55],
  ["Another", 33, 23, 14, 15]
];

print_r( 

$array[
    key(
        array_filter(
            array_column($array,2), function($a){
                if ($a == 33)
                   return false;
            return true;
        })
    )
]


);
```

Comment: Legacy codebase, restricted to PHP 4. Nice and concise though.